# Count SSRS grouped value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table of the following kind:

```
Shop     Brand1     Brand2     Brand3     Qnt
Shop1    1          0          1          2
```

There is a grouping by Brand. In the cells under the brands the formula is written in the similarity:

```
= if (count (X) / sum (X)> 0, 1, 0)
```

In result for each brand 1 or 0 is returned. I need to sum 1 and 0 in column Qnt. Column Qnt without groupings.

If it is not possible to force SSRS to count alternately the values under the brands, and then simply add them. The link to textboxes in the grouping can not be done either, that is, sum (ReportItems! TextBoxBrand.Value) will not works too. Can be it is possible on VB to write in Code?

Comment: Edit your question to include a sample of data as it is in your dataset, also include expected results based on that sample data as this will help us to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the values in the tablix, it will not be possible to build a formula that works in the totals column (*Qnt*). In order to achive this, I suggest to instead use a pre-grouping by `Shop` and `Brand` in the dataset query and calculate the 1s and 0s there. Doing this, you can use the `Sum` function in the tablix for both value and total.

Answer (score 0):

when you have for example a grouping ("GroupingByShop") in Tablix1 you can count the grouped total

```
=Count(Fields!Brand1.Value, "GroupingByShop")
```

or the ovrall value

```
=Count(Fields!Brand1.Value)
```

I dont know if it is what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.